# Set max date value to today in java swing jdatepicker

Tags: java

I want to use jdatepicker for birthdate input.
Is there any method or property or any other way to set maximum date as today in jdatepicker.

See the below code with jdatepicker 1.3.4

```
UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("text.today", "Today");
    p.put("text.month", "Month");
    p.put("text.year", "Year");
    JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
    JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel,
            new DateLabelFormatter());
```

I have implemented DateLabelFormatter class for date formatting purpose.
Though I will provide.

```
public class DateLabelFormatter extends AbstractFormatter {

private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMAT_DDMMMYYYY);

public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
    return dateFormatter.parseObject(text);
}

public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
    if (value != null) {
        Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
        return dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
    }

    return "";
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I couldn´t fix it. But I tried with JCalendar library http://toedter.com/jcalendar/ and now it's working by using the method setMaxSelectableDate.

This is my code:

```
JDateChooser chooser = new JDateChooser();
chooser.setMaxSelectableDate(new Date());
chooser.setDateFormatString("dd-MM-yyyy");
chooser.setDate(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda late, but I decided to post this in case someone need it.

How I managed to limit the max date on datepicker to today is using the DateLabelFormatter class.

```
class DateLabelFormatter extends AbstractFormatter {

private String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);

@Override
public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
    return dateFormatter.parseObject(text);
}

@Override
public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
    if (value != null) {
        Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        if (cal.getTime().after(today.getTime())) return dateFormatter.format(today.getTime());

        return dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
    }

    return "";
}}
```

This is a not a very good solution since this **didn't disable** any date after today on the datepicker. This solution merely check for the selected date, if the selected date is after the specified date (which is today) it will return the value of today's date.